# NodeJS : The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported

Tags: node.js, get, video.js

I have a NodeJS server and I'd like to serve a local video, but I get an error when getting the link to the html page that says: *The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.*

I tried on Safari and Chrome, but none of them seems to work with it.

So this is my code :

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET \"/\" requested.");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Public/index.html");
});

app.get("/videotest", function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET \"/videotest\" requested.")
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Public/vtest.html")
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server listening on port 3000")
});
```

**vtest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Video Player</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js@7/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- City -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/themes@1/dist/city/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/solid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <video class="vjs-custom video-js vjs-big-play-centered" width="960" height="540" data-setup='{}' controls>
        <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the Public folder tree :

[image]

**Note:** I tried reading the video without launching Node server and it works perfectly but not from Node localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out in my code that I just forgot to serve static files using `app.use(express.static('public');`